# How to use javap on a jar file

Tags: debian, java

I'm runnig debian buster and have a realy old java game that I played native with openjdk but I can not remember the exact version. So i tried to find out with javap with which java version the jar file is compiled.

```
javap -v java-spiele/edna_bricht_aus/Edna.jar 
Error: class not found: java-spiele/edna_bricht_aus/Edna.jar
```

default java version is

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+8-post-Debian-1deb10u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.13+8-post-Debian-1deb10u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Maybe to new. so I installed openjdk-8 from stretch repo (yes I know franken debian)
another try

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/javap -v /home/alex/java-spiele/edna_bricht_aus/Edna.jar 
Error: class not found: /home/alex/java-spiele/edna_bricht_aus/Edna.jar
```

Is it even possible to get information from a commercial game?
with openjdk-8 the game is not running it crashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`javap` expects a class, not a JAR. To disassemble a class in a JAR, add the JAR to the classpath and specify the class name; for example, using JSTL instead of your game:

```
javap -v -classpath jstl-1.2.jar org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV
```

To see the classes in a JAR, use `jar tf`; replace slashes with dots to convert a path to a package.

To figure out the versions of Java for which all the classes in a JAR were built, you might be better off extracting the classes in the JAR and running `file` on them:

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
jar xf ../java-spiele/edna_bricht_aus/Edna.jar
find . -name \*.class -exec file {} +
```

Comment: thank you java 1.6 no gaming session for me.

Comment: `javap -v` does tell you classfile version, along with a _lot_ of other stuff. Nit: given `jar tf` change slashes to dots _and remove .class_ to get classname.

Answer (score 1):

you can also specify the URL for a class in the jar to `javap` like this:

```
javap -v jar:file:///path/to/MyJar.jar!/mypkg/MyClass.class
```